# How can I reference a static, native library in NativeScript iOS?

Tags: nativescript

I found a sample project describing how to do this here:

https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-iOS-StaticLibs

But I think it is out of date - it doesn't work on {N] 1.3. I've put together a very, very simple test - a static library containing one class, with one static string. I've successfully added it to Xcode by adding the `.a` file to the linked binaries, and the path to the `.h` file in the header search paths. So far so good - if I reference it in the native code it finds it. However, when I try to do the same in a JS file, it cannot find the variable.

There are no errors associated with it, so I'm not sure where to start looking. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `module.modulemap` file to your library to instruct metadata generator for which headers should generate metadata. You can read more about modulemap files [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#module-map-language). You can find an example of modulemap file [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/ios-runtime/blob/master/tests/TestFixtures/module.modulemap). In your scenario, you have to add your `module.modulemap` in the same folder as your `.h` file and its content should be something like this:

```
module LibraryName {
    umbrella header "HeaderName.h"
    export *
    module * { export * }
}
```